# Raspberry Pi 4: Console on first HDMI screen, X11 on second HDMI screen

Tags: raspbian, hdmi, pi-4, xorg

The new Pi 4 has two HDMI Ports. After booting Raspbian, the first screen (HDMI-0) should display the console and the second screen (HDMI-1) should display the X11 desktop.

My first thought was editing good old xorg.conf but newer debians don't have this file. Do I need to change config.txt?

Not sure how to start... Thx for your help.

Comment: Good old xorg.conf is still used if you create it. X11 only use defaults if it doesn't find it.

Comment: It should be doable with [screen] and [monitor] sections and so on. But I'm unsure how to select the hdmi output by the application (console ws. xserver). I watch your question as favorite.

Comment: While getting deeper into modern X11 configurations my requirements changed. So unfortunately I cannot answer my own question. Coming from an old xorg-conf-configures-x11 mindset I found the following links useful to understand the newer (xrandr focused) approach: [How to use xrandr](https://xorg-team.pages.debian.net/xorg/howto/use-xrandr.html) and [Multihead](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Multihead).